# What happens when data is written to LATCH?

Tags: microcontroller, pic

This is what I found in PIC16F1947 data sheet:

> Reading the PORTB register reads the status of the pins,
>   whereas writing to it will write to
>   the PORT latch. All write operations
>   are read-modify-write operations.
>   Therefore, a write to a port implies
>   that the port pins are read, this
>   value is modified and then written to
>   the PORT data latch (LATB).

I'm a firmware developer and my background is Computer Science. I still struggle to understand electronics and logic in hardware level. I only have the basic knowledge.

So, I want to understand what happens when data is written to latch in hardware level.

Thank you.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Latch is a kind of memory of one bit.

Let's use the picture in manual:

[image: Generic I/O Port Operation]

When you write a bit in a I/O pin, you're storing this bit from Data Bus to the Data Register ([D-FlipFlop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_%28electronics%29)). If TRISx of this bit is 0, so data from Q of the Data Register will be in the I/O pin. Write in LATx or PORTx is the same. See below in red:

[image: Generic I/O Port Operation Write]

On the other hand, read from LATx is different of read from PORTx.

When you're reading from LATx, you're reading what is in the Data Register ([D-FlipFlop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_%28electronics%29)). See picture below in green:

[image: Generic I/O Port Operation Read LATx]

And when you read from PORTx, you're reading the actual I/O pin value. See below in blue:

[image: Generic I/O Port Operation Read PORTx]

PIC uses read-modify-write to write operations and this can be a [problem](http://data.bolton.ac.uk/staff/ks3/ECE1011/2%20ProgrammableDevices/Lectures/I1readmodifywrite.pdf), so they use this shadow register to avoid it.

Comment: +1 for linking to a place the clearly describes the (read-modify-write)[http://techref.massmind.org/techref/readmodwrite.htm] problem (and solution).

Comment: Wow, great explanation.

Comment: The two links to the read-mod-write problem are broken.

Comment: @Randomblue,I've put another link. The problem with the other link is the ']' character at the end. Just delete it in your browser address.

Comment: The [link contributed by davidcary](http://techref.massmind.org/techref/readmodwrite.htm)
A Couple more links referencing the problem:
[1](https://electrosome.com/read-modify-write-problem-pic/), [2](http://www.knutselaar.eu/pdf/ReadModifyWrite.pdf), [3](http://www.cornerstonerobotics.org/curriculum/lessons_year2/erii_rmw_problem.pdf)

Answer (score 6):

To avoid read-modify-write problems you should write to the port as a whole, rather than setting or resetting individual bits in the port. An R-M-W problem might result in a bit not being set, or another output going high, especially if output pins are sourcing or sinking a lot of current.

A "shadow register" is typically used. Set or reset bits in that, and output it to the port, to avoid R-M-W problems.

The problem is avoided with 18F PICs by the use of a separate latch, individual bits in that can be set and reset with impunity.

Comment: but i guess i don't need to write to the latch register, since writing to original port register will write to latch, right?

Comment: @Donotalo, You're right. You can write in the port register too. It does not matter.

Comment: @Donotalo: It's possible to write to the port register, but I'd recommend as a matter of habit writing to the LATx registers on those processors that have them, and regarding the PORTx registers as read-only. A "blind" store to a PORTx register (e.g. PORTB = 0x42;) will behave no differently from one to LATBx, and a read-modify-write to a PORTx register (e.g. PORTB |= 0x02;) will have an effect which will either be the same as LATx or else differ in a most-likely-undesirable way. BTW, some of the later pre-Microchip PICs offered LATx; I don't know why Microchip took years (decades?) to do so.

Comment: +1 for mentioning that PIC18F chips (aka "16-bit instruction PICs) have the LAT register, while PIC16F chips (aka "14-bit instruction PICs") require simulating the LAT register in software ("shadow register").