# Bit shifting and PORT value on PIC18F4520

Tags: pic, mplab, port

I am working on a PIC18f4520. 
To do my test, I have connected a led to the pic. The following items are the steps I would like to do :

- Save the value of the port set for the LED (which blinks according to the ISR subroutine I wrote, and can be look at in this case as a clock signal). For this I did :

  ```
  unsigned char portValue;   // initialization
  TRISBbits.TRISB5 = 0;      // LED on RB5 set as output

  portValue = PORTBbits.RB5; // operation in the main while loop
  ```
- Left shift the bits of **portValue** by one but with the insertion of the **RB5** value. To illustrate :

  ```
  --> if RB5 = 1, I would have portValue = 0b0000 0001 
  --> at t+1, RB5 = 0 then portValue = 0b0000 0010
  --> at t+2, RB5 = 1 then portValue = 0b0000 0101
  --> and so on (RB5 taking 1 or 0 and no other value)
  ```

With what I have wrote so far I can only do a left shifting. But I can't find a way to "add" the RB5...

Does something like

```
portValue = portValue<<(&PORTBbits.RB5);
```

could work ?
Bit shifting operations are quite new to me so my questions can be odd.

Anyhow, thanks in advance !

Comment: On the 18F you should use `LAT` not `PORT` when writing.  See: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/28750/on-pic18-series-when-should-i-use-lat-register-and-when-port/28753#28753

Comment: Fantastic guys ! Thanks a lot !! Your explanations are clear and I understand better how the bit shifting works now.

Both solution work perfectly. I am going to push forward my code and I'll see which one is more efficient for my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bitshifting works like this:

```
result = value << amount
```

this shifts the bits of the variable *value* by *amount* of bits to the left. Use >> for right shifting.

So before you store your new bit, you want do shift *portValue* by one bit, like this:

```
portValue = portValue << 1;
```

Now the first bit will be 0 by default and you can store your new bit there like this:

```
portValue = portValue | PORTBbits.RB5;
```

This assumes that the variable PORTBbits.RB5 will only have the values 0 or 1 so every other bit except bit 0 is always 0. To make sure of this you can mask PORTBbits.RB5 with 0x01 like this:

```
portValue = portValue | (PORTBbits.RB5 & 0x01);
```

This will make sure that only the first bit will be changed.

This can now be combined in one line if you like:

```
portValue = (portValue << 1 ) | (PORTBbits.RB5 & 0x01);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
portValue <<= 1; //left shift every time round
portValue |= (PORTBbits.RB5) ? 1 : 0; //set LSB of portValue if RB5 is true
```